scoping in javascript, global vs. local
I wrote the following code in my console, just to understand something
a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    console.log(a); // prints 10;
    return; 
    function a() {} // is this the same as writing var a = () => {}; ?
}
b(); // returns undefined
console.log(a); // returns 1

I don't understand how this can be right. a is a global variable (changed inside the function). Why is it 1 in the end, and not 10?

function statements are hoisted, so function a() declares a local variable, even if it's after return.

function a() {} is not the same as var a = () => {};
